# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation must be added manually to new project each time

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, nuget

I am creating load of small MVC projects with .NET Core 8 and I've run into this odd problem, that in order to run new, empty project with MVC I have to actually manually add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation package from Nuget and modify Program.cs by adding:

`builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

When creating the project I use .NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller). I also use standard settings.

I followed some courses on .NET Core 8 and each time, after following the steps from the course the new project loads correctly and in my case, I have to add the package and service or otherwise it won't work.

Any ideas why that is?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue after all, so I'll post it here for future generations.

The solution turns out to be trivial - Visual Studio Update. The problem had nothing to do with neither the actual code, nor with the configuration of the project or the build, nor with the builder of the application.

I've updated Visual Studio to version 17.7 and the issue went away. Good luck to anyone trying to fix it!